# How to automate uploading files and do some tasks on website with python?

Tags: python, selenium, pyautogui

I'm new with this and I could really use help. I put my designs on site (https://society6.com - not my site) but it's not a simple upload process, because the website, doesn't load metadata (title, description, and keywords) which takes a lot of time. I was wondering how can I automate the whole process, starting from uploading, checking all required check statements (always the same) and copying metadata, and at the end publishing.

I use Linux and I would like to upload multiple images. One after another one.

I'm comfortable with python, but I have never used similar modules. I have found two Selenium (https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and PyAutoGUI (https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Can you recommend me a better one for me and help me save time. And if you know of similar projects, please let me know about them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If this is your site you are uploading to, and can access it via SSH, you can use Python to create your command that you can then pass to the server via a subcommand. I do this alot with my websites. You can then use rsync to push your files from your computer up to the server. If this is what you're trying to do, I can give more details how to set it all up.

Comment: If I understand you well, this way I only get to upload but not to publish. I need to upload, input the metadata, agree with terms of conditions and publish, I'm not sure that I can do that with SSH, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Okay, since uploading the files themselves isn't publishing on this site, sounds like this is not your site, and you're trying to make this process easier. My only thought would be to use a macro application where you can record your actions on the website, and then repeat that through the app.

Comment: Hmm, this is an interesting idea. I'll try, thanks!

Comment: This may be what you were originally looking for, a way to do it in Python. I haven't done this, but it looks like this page may be helpful.
https://towardsdatascience.com/automating-submission-forms-with-python-94459353b03e

Comment: Yes, it's something like this... Thank you very much!